# Why does node show different versions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is this error displayed if node version v16.17.1?

[image]

ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v10.19.0

UP---

I had several versions of node. The old version was installed by default. Solved the problem using nvm.

Comment: Have you tried running either of the suggested commands?

Comment: @robertc yes, no result

Comment: What input produces the first output? It looks like the first node version in your PATH and the the node version for the script are different.

Comment: @jabaa This message is always in the terminal. I'm trying to delete it.

Answer (score -1):

I had several versions of node. The old version was installed by default. Solved the problem using nvm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).